# How do I pass my array data coming from api to another ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new in iOS.

I'm trying to pass my array data to another view controller through prepareforsegue method.

And this api is called inside the @IBAction func ButtonTapped( ).

```
class FirstVc {
var location = [Any]()
  self.clientrequest.request(url: "http://api.details.in/api/users/alllocation", method: .GET, completion: {
                    res , err in           
let json = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: res , options: .prettyPrinted)
let decode = try! JSONDecoder().decode(SelectLocation.self, from:json)

            self.location = decode.states
   //I'm getting all locations here
               print(self.location)

  })
}
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.destination is SecondVc
        {
            let vc = segue.destination as?  SecondVc
     //here I'm assigning the variable and while I'm printing location here then also I'm getting the value
                vc?.mineSpillere2 = self.location
        }
    }

class SecondVc{
 @IBOutlet weak var selectState: UILabel!
    var mineSpillere2 = [Any]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
//While I'm trying to print mineSpillere2 here I', getting []
     selectState.text = mineSpillere2 as? String
    }    
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: hello @rmaddy .. I already  referred above link but I'm not getting my solution.

Comment: I think your code is incomplete. Please provide full compilable code. Or make assumptions like "I'm initialising my variable in the init() of this class."

Comment: I called this API on buttonTapped() action . Do you need my model class ????  @thisIsTheFoxe

Comment: Not necessarily, but it would've been great if you mentioned that in your question/code so it's easier to follow you..

Comment: ok sir @thisIsTheFoxe

Comment: where do you call `performSegue` function?

Comment: I'm calling it inside the buttonTapped()  after assigning the decoded values to the location variable @SoroushShahi

Comment: got it. checkout my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, the problem is that web service request is not executed asynchronously but synchronously. In other words, your segue is already performed before `decode.states` is assigned to the `location` variable.

The solution is to call `performSegue` function in the completion block:

```
self.clientrequest.request(url: "http://api.details.in/api/users/alllocation", method: .GET, completion: {
                res , err in           
let json = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: res , options: .prettyPrinted)
let decode = try! JSONDecoder().decode(SelectLocation.self, from:json)

        self.location = decode.states
        self.performSegue(identifier: "your identifier", 
       sender: nil)
//I'm getting all locations here
           print(self.location)

})
```

Second,
Make sure your segue is assigned from VC1 to VC2 not Button to VC2.

Comment: are you sure you are parsing server response correctly? set a breakpoint right before performing segue and check if self.location is assigned properly.

Comment: I printed the value of self.location in func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) then also I'm getting my output.... after this I'm assigning this output to the variable of SecondVc..

Comment: so you mean you have your data in `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` but when the segue is performed, you do not have your data in the next View Controller?

Comment: check the storyboard one more time and make sure your segue is correctly assigned. I presume you have set multiple segues by mistake. Also set an identifier for it and check it in an if condition inside `prepareForSegue` function

Comment: I have created a segue from button to the SecondVc and I had given identifier also.. And why we are assigning ```self.performSegue(identifier: "your identifier", 
       sender: nil)``` sender as nil

Comment: Do not assign it through the button. Assign it from VC1 to VC2 not from button to VC2.

Comment: yes sir.. I got my answer .. I assigned the segue from VC1 to VC2...   THANKS ALOT....

Answer (score 0):

One problem might be that you don't actually assign the variable (because `vc` may be nil). Also you may want to use segueIdentifiers, especially if you have more than one. To make sure that you do so, you may want to use something like this:

```swift
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let vc = segue.destination as? SecondVc //, segue.identifier = "YOUR_SEGUE_ID"
    {
        vc.mineSpillere2 = self.location
    } else { print("SecondVc couldn't be initialised!") }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are several way to pass this in another ViewController. Good way is make a model class and pass model object to another vc .
Or might be another short and easy solution is make Global variable. So you can access it from any ViewController class. like

```
    var myGloblArray= [Any]()
//add your result array in this array , you can access it from second VC Directly.

    class FirstVc {
    ...

    }
```

Comment: in output I'm getting [] only square brackets... while printing it in SecondVc...

Comment: assign your result array to -> myGloblArray . Make sure both carry are same type.

Comment: give me your api result output